# Packet Tracer 7.2 freezes while trying to save file

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, cisco

I have a file `topology_1.pkt` saved in default save location of `packettracer 7.2`. Now if I try to save another work with filename beginning with "`t`" (let's say `topology_2.pkt`), When I hit "`t`" from keyboard to write the filename a suggestion appears `topology_1.pkt` and everything freezes. It seems like every time this happens only way out is a forced restart.

This problem happens in `ubuntu 16.04`. I thought that upgrading to `18.04` might solve the problem. But this problem is still persists.

Comment: Issue still there (and still annoying) in 7.3.0.

Comment: Happens in version 7.3.1.0362 on Ubuntu 20.04 too. It's frustrating!

Comment: Bug still here in 8.0.1.

Comment: This is something you all should be contacting Cisco or whoever makes Packet Tracer about.  This is a bug report in that application and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's going to help you. But in my case what I did is or what I will be doing is once you click save as and Save dialog box appears I first type the file name before going to the actual directory the file needs to be saved. Once you give the name for the file then locate the directory you want to save the file in and Save. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter this problem too, but I don't know why this problem always happen. The solution is, save your work with different name, so filename suggestion wouldn't appear

Comment: Yes ,I'm doing kinda same. After saving a file I move it to another folder to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. PacketTracer V7.2.1. I don't know how to handle the problem but there is another way if you don't want to Force Reboot your system (either with `Alt + SysRq + REISUB` or `Power key`).

You can simply press `Ctrl + Alt + F3`, -> login, -> type `top` and enter. You can see the PID of PacketTracer (For example 6570), Just type `kill 6570` and then go back to your GUI with `Ctrl + Alt + F2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ps aux | more
```

and looking for ./PacketTracer7 (in my case)

```
$ kill pid (./PacketTracer7 pid)
```

Comment: How is this answer the question? Does killing the process prevent it from freezing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be addressed in version 8.1.0.0722.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1197103)

Comment: Hi @tejas-lotlikar. It is not an answer because there is no question. This here is a bug report (maybe the core issue is that a bug report is off-scope in itself). Some people have provided workarounds for impacted versions, this response informs potential readers of the first version in which the issue is addressed by the editor. It kind of closes the issue, if not answering a question.

Comment: in that case, a comment could have be made, rather than writing an answer :)

Comment: I'm on 8.1.1.0022, and the problem still happens when I save from Packet Tracer.